# AWK match string, not Regex

Tags: awk, regular-expression

How do I match a string with AWK?

Say I have the string `[(*.+` it should only match strings containing the string `[(*.+`.

The string is entered by the user, so if you know a cli utility that can escape regexes it may work too.

**Edit:**

It should also match strings containing the string, such as `foo[(*.+bar`.

Comment: Is awk required?  Can you use `fgrep` / `grep -F`?

Comment: awk is required

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) does string comparison with the `==` operator, and string searching with the `index(haystack, needle)` function.

```
read -r string # user types [(*.+
{ echo 'stuff [(*.+ stuff'; echo ')]*.+'; } | awk -v string="$string" 'index($0, string)'
# output: 'stuff [(*.+ stuff'
```

Comment: I need it to match where the string is a substring also, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, awk treats chars within "" as string and within // as regexp:

```
[root@me ~]# echo "[(*.+" | gawk '"[(*.+"'
[(*.+
[root@me~]# echo "[(*.+" | gawk '/[(*.+/'
gawk: /[(*.+/
gawk:  ^ unterminated regexp
gawk: fatal: Unmatched [ or [^: /[(*.+//
```

Comment: `echo "[(*.+" | gawk '"wtf"'` will also display the same result as your example, but still not solves the problem.